# Value of submit button not being passed to ActionForm in Struts 1.x

Tags: struts

I am trying to implement multiple submit buttons in a Struts jsp.  To do so, I am passing the value of the submit button to the ActionForm and reading that value.  My setup is like this:

```
JSP
...snip...
<form name = "formName" action = "action.do" onSubmit = "return myFunc()" method = "POST">
<input type = "text" name = "myValue" /> 
<input type = "submit" name = "myButton" value = "Submit" />
</form>
...snip...

MyForm
...snip...
String myButton;
String myValue;
[Generated getters and setters]
...snip...
```

As far as I can tell, the submit button from the jsp should submit a value of 'Submit' to the myButton variable in MyForm, but when I try to access it in the Action Class I always get a value of null.

I know that my struts-config.xml file is configured properly because the text input in the jsp successfully populates the 'myValue' variable in MyForm, which can be read by my Action Class.

Is there something special about submit buttons in Struts that I am missing? It seems everything should work...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a input type hidden for that,  `value` property of submit buttons is only used for text on the button not for sending that value with the rest of the form data.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to submit the value of the submit button itself?  It seems like there should be...

Comment: No there isn't, for the value to be sent you have to put it on a input text or input hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using Struts JSP tags to define the form and the submit button. Why dont you use Struts JSP tags?

```
<html:form action="action.do">
<html:submit property="myButton" value="Submit"/>
```

Hope it helps